# Interrupt handling with push buttons in ARMv7

Tags: assembly, arm, interrupt, armv7

I am trying to trigger an interrupt when a push button is pressed but I can't get service_irq to trigger. The push buttons light up green and the _start function seems to work, as far as I can tell. Any ideas what the problem is and how I can fix it?

I am using ARMv7 and the [DE1-SoC](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ql9oqPQA1GYTy_hATf3HHjnC6jQ9fbOtMwh-6XTW86A/edit?usp=sharing) in [CPUlator](https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm-de1soc).

My code:

```
.org 0x00000000
.equ SVC_MODE_STACK_BASE, 0x3FFFFFFF - 3 // set SVC stack to top of DDR3 memory
.equ IRQ_MODE_STACK_BASE, 0xFFFFFFFF - 3 // set IRQ stack to A9 onchip memory
.equ GIC_CPU_INTERFACE_BASE, 0xFFFEC100
.equ GIC_DISTRIBUTOR_BASE, 0xFFFED000
.equ PUSH_BUTTONS_BASE, 0xff200050
.equ DISPLAYS_BASE, 0xff200020
.equ PUSH_BUTTONS_IRQ, 73

B _start // reset vector
B SERVICE_UND // undefined instruction vector
B SERVICE_SVC // software interrrupt vector
B SERVICE_ABT_INST // aborted prefetch vector
B SERVICE_ABT_DATA // aborted data vector
.word 0 // unused vector
B SERVICE_IRQ // IRQ interrupt vector
B SERVICE_FIQ // FIQ interrupt vector

.text
.global _start
_start:
    // Step 1: Set up the stack for Supervisor Mode
    ldr sp, =SVC_MODE_STACK_BASE

    // Step 2: Configure the GIC
    bl CONFIG_GIC
    
    // Step 3: Configure push buttons interrupts
    ldr r0, =PUSH_BUTTONS_BASE // Load base address of pushbutton registers
    mov r1, #0xF               // Enable interrupts for the keys
    str r1, [r0, #8]           // Write to the appropriate offset to enable interrupts

    // Step 4: Enable IRQ interrupts in the processor
    cpsie i                    // Enable IRQ interrupts

    // Step 5: Jump to main program loop
    B LOOP
    
LOOP:
    B LOOP
    
SERVICE_IRQ:
    PUSH {R0-R7, LR}

    /* Read the Interrupt Acknowledge Register (ICCIAR) from the CPU interface */
    LDR R4, =GIC_CPU_INTERFACE_BASE
    LDR R5, [R4, #0x0C] // read from ICCIAR
    
    // Set the display to 0 to test if service_irq is triggered
    LDR R0, =DISPLAYS_BASE
    MOV R1, #0b00111111
    STR R1, [R0]

    B EXIT_IRQ

EXIT_IRQ:
    /* Write to the End of Interrupt Register (ICCEOIR) */
    STR R5, [R4, #0x10] // write to ICCEOIR

    // Restore registers and return from interrupt.
    POP {R0-R7, LR}
    SUBS PC, LR, #4  // Atomically restores CPSR from SPSR and returns to interrupted instruction.

SERVICE_UND:
    B SERVICE_UND
SERVICE_SVC:
    B SERVICE_SVC
SERVICE_ABT_DATA:
    B SERVICE_ABT_DATA
SERVICE_ABT_INST:
    B SERVICE_ABT_INST
SERVICE_FIQ:
    B SERVICE_FIQ
    

CONFIG_GIC:
    PUSH {LR}
    /* To configure a specific interrupt ID:
    * 1. set the target to cpu0 in the ICDIPTRn register
    * 2. enable the interrupt in the ICDISERn register */
    /* CONFIG_INTERRUPT (int_ID (R0), CPU_target (R1)); */
    MOV R1, #1 // this field is a bit-mask; bit 0 targets cpu0
    BL CONFIG_INTERRUPT
    /* configure the GIC CPU Interface */
    LDR R0, =GIC_CPU_INTERFACE_BASE // base address of CPU Interface, 0xFFFEC100
    /* Set Interrupt Priority Mask Register (ICCPMR) */
    LDR R1, =0xFFFF // enable interrupts of all priorities levels
    STR R1, [R0, #0x04]
    /* Set the enable bit in the CPU Interface Control Register (ICCICR).
    * This allows interrupts to be forwarded to the CPU(s) */
    MOV R1, #1
    STR R1, [R0]
    /* Set the enable bit in the Distributor Control Register (ICDDCR).
    * This enables forwarding of interrupts to the CPU Interface(s) */
    LDR R0, =GIC_DISTRIBUTOR_BASE   // 0xFFFED000
    STR R1, [R0]
    POP {PC}

CONFIG_INTERRUPT:
    PUSH {R4-R5, LR}
    /* Configure Interrupt Set-Enable Registers (ICDISERn).
    * reg_offset = (integer_div(N / 32) * 4
    * value = 1 << (N mod 32) */
    LSR R4, R0, #3 // calculate reg_offset
    BIC R4, R4, #3 // R4 = reg_offset
    LDR R2, =0xFFFED100 // Base address of ICDISERn
    ADD R4, R2, R4 // R4 = address of ICDISER
    AND R2, R0, #0x1F // N mod 32
    MOV R5, #1 // enable
    LSL R2, R5, R2 // R2 = value
    /* Using the register address in R4 and the value in R2 set the
    * correct bit in the GIC register */
    LDR R3, [R4] // read current register value
    ORR R3, R3, R2 // set the enable bit
    STR R3, [R4] // store the new register value
    /* Configure Interrupt Processor Targets Register (ICDIPTRn)
    * reg_offset = integer_div(N / 4) * 4
    * index = N mod 4 */
    BIC R4, R0, #3 // R4 = reg_offset
    LDR R2, =0xFFFED800 // Base address of ICDIPTRn
    ADD R4, R2, R4 // R4 = word address of ICDIPTR
    AND R2, R0, #0x3 // N mod 4
    ADD R4, R2, R4 // R4 = byte address in ICDIPTR
    /* Using register address in R4 and the value in R2 write to
    * (only) the appropriate byte */
    STRB R1, [R4]
    POP {R4-R5, PC}

.end
```

Comment: You do not return from the IRQ at all (UNEXPECTED???).  You can use `cpsie` instead of the mode manipulation.  It looks like you are manipulating GIC addresses instead of GIC register values, etc.  Why switch to SVC mode and set stack.  Just set stack.  If you were in another mode to begin with, then where is that stack set?

Comment: @artlessnoise Thank you for the respone! I have modified the code, but I still can't get the service_irq to trigger? Are you able to provide a code example?

Comment: No, I have no idea about the SOC.  Does the GIC need a clock?  Is the clock dynamically enabled?  Do you have IO/Pin muxing, etc?  Generally, people do as little as possible in assembler and then transition to 'C' code.  You need to keep registers straight and lots of other issues in assembler. There are both system level issues and assembler issues that are possible.

Comment: @artlessnoise I found some documentation for the SOC, but I'm not entirally sure how it works. I know it's a lot to ask, but would you be able to figure it out by looking at the documentation? Or maybe guide me in the right direction. Thank you!